# HTMLEditor control's value lost after postback

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.0) project that uses custom controls for its UI. One such control is the HTMLEditor control from the AJAXControl toolkit. The moment I set a value using its insertHTML method using Javascript, the set value is lost after the postback. However, the same is not true with other controls (like Textbox).

I hooked up all the page events (preinit, init, preload, load etc.) just to see whether or not the values are being loaded from the ViewState. The moment it reaches the Load event, I see the value that I set in the Javascript for the HTMLEditor control is lost, however for other controls the values are retained.

Interestingly, when I added the same control in one of my test projects to reproduce the behavior, I could see the value being retained just before the page's load event (using the same AJAXControl toolkit's HTMLEditor control).

Am I overlooking something in the code? (I must be - as it is failing).

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel ?

Comment: It can be a lot of things. I think move your porject to new test project which you said it works fine :)

Comment: @Aristos: Nope - there's is no UpdatePanel as such.

Comment: Does your editor has the toolbars and preview enabled? If you do have the "Preview" option enable can you switch back and forth and test if the control retains the value.

Comment: The editor has the toolbar. Btw, I couldn't find the Preview property for the editor?